# Columns changed

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I am working on a Budget Request report. In previous transformations the people who see this report just wanted to know which rows of data changed (IE it which Budget Requests were updated/changed/etc.) but now they would like to see how they have changed from the previous requests. Essentially, I just want to see the columns in Pentaho be marked if they changed. Is that possible in PDI?

Previously I was using the Merge Rows (diff) step, is there something similar for columns?

Comment: You might want to provide an outline of your current data structure and job. It sounds like you have historical different data in different columns, rather than normalised. Show an example and we might be able to help.

Comment: After some research we were able to do it with a SQL query and executing it in Pentaho. Thanks